# Configuring AMD Raedon 6700m on Dell 4600m precision. Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ati, catalyst

I'm having a nightmare with Ubuntu 12.10 due to my graphic card. I have a Dell precision 4600m laptop coming with an AMD Raedon 6700m HD graphic card working on Ubuntu 12.10.

Recently, I wanted to use 2 identical screens that I have in my office. First, I used one of them and I got the error related to the resolution. I modified the xorg.conf to a bigger virtual resolution. It worked (I used the display manager in the "system settings"). On the other hand, I couldn't use the second one (using HDMI).

From the "Software sources", I modified the the driver to the open source one and everything worked fine for the three screens. After some time, I noticed that, sometimes, I had to force restart my PC because it was stuck with black screen on the boot (after choosing between Windows and Ubuntu). I did that many times. After some research on internet, I decided to install the Catalyst driver and here started the whole war!

The problem now is that I can use only two screens (if I try to use the third screen, an error saying "could not set the configuration for CRTC 148"). Even if the Catalyst tool allow me to set the 3 screens, when I reboot (I need a reboot every time I modify the configuration in Catalyst control center), I can't set them through the "display manager".

The other problem is that when I use one of the screens with my laptop screen, I get one of them with half screen disabled where I can't reach it with the mouse.

My configuration:

Ubuntu 12.10. 
Catalyst Driver packaging version: 9.00.11-120920a-147436C-ATI.
Two identical screens' resolution: 1280 × 1024.
Laptop screen's resolution: 1366 × 768.

Here is my xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-LVDS"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "2560 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1366x768"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP9"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "1280 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1280x1024"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-CRT1"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1280x1024"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-LVDS" "0-LVDS"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP9" "0-DFP9"
    Option      "Monitor-CRT1" "0-CRT1"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Virtual   3926 1366
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Thanks for the help :)